# ImageButton não chama o evento 'Click'

Tags: asp.net

Tenho um ImageButton dentro de uma grid, quando clico no botão este não chama o evento click correspondente.
Alguma ideia do que possa estar ocasionando esse erro?

Comment: poste o código que você usa no botão e no metodo chamado pelo evento para podermos ajudar

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Evento onclik não funciona dentro do grid, para gerenciar os evento dentro do grid use o OnRowCommand

Saiba sobre como utilizar o OnRowCommand [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava ocorrendo pelo seguinte motivo:
A grid é carregada através de um *ObjectDataSource* e neste foi habilitado a paginação, acontece que a consulta do *SelectCountMethod* estava diferente do *SelectMethod* e isso estava causando o erro.

Obrigado pela ajuda e atenção de vocês.